# How to plot the result of nintegrate?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I am trying to plot f as a function of z (x and z are real):

```
f[z_] := NIntegrate[x^5*(x^2 - 5/2)*Exp[-x^2]*Exp[-45^{1/2}*Abs[z]/x^4], {x, 0, Infinity}];
```

Comment: I am trying to plot f as a function of z (x and z are real)

Comment: Have you tried `Plot`?

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

```
f[z_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[x^5*(x^2-5/2)*
          Exp[-x^2]*Exp[-45^{1/2}*Abs[z]/x^4],{x,0,Infinity}];

 Plot[ f[z],{z,0,10},Frame->True,
     FrameLabel->{{"f(z)",None},{"z","my integral"}},
     GridLines->Automatic,GridLinesStyle->LightGray,
     PlotStyle->Red,BaseStyle->12]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You don't even need `?NumericQ` any more. (I forget when that change happened. A straight plot of the OP's `f` worked fine in V11.2.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think it is safer to leave `?NumericQ` in the definition. Just in case user tried to invoke `f[a]` somewhere else in the code where `a` is symbol and not numeric, otherwise, they will get error. I see though that for the `Plot` command itself, it does not need it. I remember it used to need it before.

Comment: thanks guys; i am new in mathematica. seems the forum working well, thought i would give it a try. cheers